# connecting to oracle db from python using a config file

Tags: python-3.x, oracle

I am pretty much new to this concept.
Currently, I am connecting to oracle database directly using the credentials within a python script but I want to store the connection string in a text file or a separate .py file and call them as I use the same credentials for multiple scripts.

I am using cx_oracle and sqlalchemy packages to connect to two databases as I extract data from the source and push it to the target(both the source and target are oracle databases).

```
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('shost', 'sport', service_name='sservice_name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='suser', password='spw', dsn = dsn_tns)


engine = create_engine('oracle://tuser:tpw@thost:tport/tservice_name')
```

I'd really want to automate this process as I reuse the same connection string in multiple scripts and I'd really appreciate if I can get some help.

Comment: Maybe you can create a new Python file such as db.py and include the commands above in a function. Then you could import db in your other files and run db.yourfunctionname and it would return your conn and engine values?

Comment: The cx_Oracles examples all do this 
see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/SampleEnv.py and https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/Query.py